# Chanuka candles if missed the night

Tags: halacha, blessing, chanuka, zemanim, lighting

If someone, not on purpose, did not light chanuka candles at night, should he light during the day? With or without a brocho?

Comment: To what end? A lit candle during the day isn't noticeable at all.

Comment: @DoubleAA So their is no reason to. I saw in chaider and in shuls that only daven shachris that they light during the day. You are saying that if not for chinuch no reason or even for chinuch their is no reson to

Comment: Do you have reason to believe there would be a difference if one neglected to light intentionally?

Comment: @WAF to pay up a shmona Esray intentionally whould make a problem

Comment: Perhaps including the parallel analysis in the question would strengthen it. Or it might reveal more about it for you and the future answerer to learn from.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Shulchan Aruch O.C. 672:2](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x3050)

> שכח או הדד ולא הדליק [....] ומיהו הני מילי לכתחילה; אבל אם עבר זה הזמן ולא הדליק, מדליק והולך כל הלילה. ואם עבר כל הלילה ולא הדליק, אין לו תשלומין
>
> If one forgot and didn't light, or purposefully didn't light [....] however, this is only [*lechatchila*](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/702/5323); if [the end of sunset] has passed and one didn't light, they should light for the entire night.  If the whole night passed and they did not light, there is no makeup for it.

Lighting time is only at night, and it makes no difference if the lighting was missed on purpose or by accident.

Comment: The main purpose of that edit was to put the link closer to the target *seif* ....if you feel that the edit went to far, [1] remove all extra stuff [2] ping me here to let me know about it, so I won't do it again. Freilichen Chanuka! :)